# Generate JAX-WS web services

Tags: web-services, jax-ws

I have a java class which has only one method, which returns an object, of a class and this class is in a jar, from this class I want to generate a JAX-WS web service, but since the class is out of the package, it gives me an error "The wsgen tool returned errors".
Is there any way to fix this?

trying to create an empty class inside the same package, of the class i want to generate the web service from, it worked